# prove that $sin$ is differentiable at 0, and find the derivative at 0.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Question: Assume the inequality $|x-\sin(x)|\le x^2$.Prove that $\sin$ is differentiable at 0, and find the derivative at 0.

Attempt:   $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\sin(x)-sin(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\sin(x)}{x} $. I have to show that it exists, but don't know how to use the assumption in the question  $|x-\sin(x)|\le x^2$. Could you give some help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $$\frac{\sin x }{x} = \frac{\sin x - x}{x} + 1 = 1 + O(x).$$

Comment: Have you heard of l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: You must mean $|x-\sin x|\le x^2.$  What you have written doesn't make sense.  Try adding and subtracting $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: And beware, the absolute value bars enclose your whole inequality, that doesn't make sense

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik L'Hospital's rule requires knowing $\sin'$ in advance, and using it to compute $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x / x$ is circular.

Comment: Do you know the inequality $x \ge \sin x$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\sin(x)}{x}$$

$$\bigg |\frac {\sin(x)}{x} -1\bigg| =    \bigg |\frac {\sin(x)-x}{x} \bigg| \le    \bigg |\frac {x^2}{x} \bigg | = |x|\to 0   $$

Thus         $$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\sin(x)}{x} =1 $$